Not getting WebGL.js file for ThreeJS
PS D:\HTML, CSS and JS\Three JS> npm start

start
parcel index.html

Server running at http://localhost:1234
 Build failed.
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'three/addons/capabilities/WebGL.js' from './main.js'
1 | import * as THREE from 'three';


2 | import {WebGL} from 'three/addons/capabilities/WebGL.js';
|                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
3 |
4 | if ( WebGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {

@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file './addons/capabilities/WebGL.js' from module 'three'
These three commands I have used to setup my Three JS Project for the first time.your text
npm install --save three
npm install --save-dev parcel
npm install three-stdlib
I expect that anybody who have well experience of three js, WebGL, node, npm and npx he/she will provide better solution for it. I have searched on Chat GPT as well as on Stackoverflow but I am still in the problem.

Maybe your version of parcel does not support export maps which means you can't use the addons alias. Does it work if you import the module like so: import { WebGL } from 'three/examples/jsm/capabilities/WebGL.js';.

Still doesn't work it gives the another error
Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist

after importing this:
import {WebGL} from 'three/examples/jsm/capabilities/WebGL.js';
